# Python Kivy Audio Progress Bar

Tags: python, аудио, kivy

Как привязать активную аудио к прогресс бару

```
    from kivy._event import EventDispatcher
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar


    class MyApp(App, EventDispatcher):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('dummy.mp3')

        def build(self):
            mainbl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            bl = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
            mainbl.add_widget(bl)
            bl.add_widget(Button(text='1-ая песня',
                                 on_press=self.btn_first))
            bl.add_widget(Button(text='2-ая песня',
                                 on_press=self.btn_second))
            pb = ProgressBar(max=10,
                             size_hint=(None, None),
                             size=('600', '60'))
            mainbl.add_widget(pb)
            return mainbl

        def btn_first(self, instance):
            if self.sound.state == "play":
                self.sound.stop()
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('01. Feed The Machine.mp3')
            self.sound.play()

        def btn_second(self, instance):
            if self.sound.state == "play":
                self.sound.stop()
            self.sound = SoundLoader.load('02. Coin For The Ferryman.mp3')
            self.sound.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ таков, обновляя каждые 0.5 секунд прогресс бар через класс Clock модуля

```
    ...

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.pbprogress, 0.5)

    ...

    def pbprogress(self, instance):
        if self.sound.state == 'play':
            self.pb.value = self.sound.get_pos()
```